# Mongoose: When you $pull an element from a sub-array, can you remove that sub-array item if it is now empty?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I `$pull` the last member out of the `members` array, can I then remove that room? Given the document below, I would want `rooms` to end up being an empty array.

```
var query = {game:'/donut_fun', 'rooms.roomname': 'Joey\'s Room'};
var update = {$pull: {'rooms.$.members': player}};
GamesModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function(err, doc){...
```

And here's my resulting document after that update. Note that the room no longer has any members so I want `rooms` to just be an empty array now. I don't care about `Joey's Room` anymore.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588e4d64c23324935a061123"),
    "game" : "/donut_fun",
    "__v" : 0,
    "rooms" : [
        {
            "members" : [ ],
            "timestamp" : 1485720932863,
            "roomname" : "Joey's Room"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up just doing two separate operations, pull the member out first, and then find all empty rooms and remove them. I'll leave this open and maybe someone will tell me how to do it in one.